# OR and And are not working in elastic as expected

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using elastic 2.4 and I have written below query:

```
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "prefix": {
                    "firstname": "guneet"
                }
            }, {
                "prefix": {
                    "lastname": "guneet"
                }
            }],
            "must": [{
                "terms": {
                    "activities.id": ["1"]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

Which is not returning me results as expected. It should give me result where activities.id match **AND** firstname or lastname match. But it is returning me results where activities.id are matching and ignoring should condition i.e it is returning me all the records where activities.id is matching irrespective of firstname or lastname.

I have taken reference from [combining filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html)

My queries MySql version should be like:
select * from users where (firstname like "%guneet%" or lastname like "%guneet%") and activities.id = [1,2].

Any suggestions that how I can mold my query to get something like above mysql query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `bool/must` clause, you need to add a [`minimum_should_match` clause](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and it will work:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "minimum_should_match": 1,
        "should": [{
            "prefix": {
                "firstname": "guneet"
            }
        }, {
            "prefix": {
                "lastname": "guneet"
            }
        }],
        "must": [{
            "terms": {
                "activities.id": ["1"]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this help ?